# Angular not POSTing multipart data so express doesn't receive a thing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, busboy, multer

I have a form with 2 file and a text area to post to the serverside made with node.js
to handle the upload part on node/express(4.0) I used multer.
While to handle the upload from the angular side I relayed on [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

I'm trying to keep the express part super simple for now just to test out the fact that it actually works

/// NODE JS EXPRESS

```
        app.use(multer({    dest: __dirname + '/public/uploads/', 
                            rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
                                return filename; //.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + Date.now()
                            }
                      }))
```

/// ANGULAR

```
        cmsApp.controller("MyController", ['$scope', '$location', '$upload', function($scope, $location, $upload) {
            $scope.title = $location;


            //$scope.saveMiscs = function() {
            $scope.submit = function() {
              console.log("saving miscs");
              var file_1 = $scope.formfile1;
              var file_2  = $scope.formfile2;

              //console.log('file is ', JSON.stringify(file_regole), " + " + JSON.stringify(file_statuto));
              $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                    url: '/api/misc/filupload1', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                    file: file_1,       // or list of files ($files) for html5 only
                  }).progress(function(evt) {
                    console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    console.log("upload completed: ", data);
                  });
            };


            $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
                $scope.files = angular.copy($files);
                console.log($scope.files); // Returns my object
            }


            $scope.setFiles = function(element) {
            $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                console.log(element.files);
                if(element.id == "form__file1")
                  file_1 = element.files;
                else if(element.id == "form__file2")
                  file_2 = element.files;
              });
            };

        }]);
```

/// ANGULAR HTML

```
    <form id="modify_form" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="MyController" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="intro_detail" style="margin-top:36px;">
            <div class="dotted blue"></div>
            <div class="box_title">Documents</div>
            Load file 1 here<br>
            <input type="file" id="form_1_fld" class="" name="" 
                    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this);" ng-model="file_1"/><br>
            <br>
            Load file 2 here<br>
            <input type="file" id="form_2_fld" class="" name="" 
                    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this);" ng-model="file_1"/>
            <div class="dotted spacer_small blue"></div>
        </div><!-- END INTRO DETAIL -->

        <div class="form_viewport">

            <div class="full_container">
                <label>Write something in here:</label><br>
                <textarea ng-model="text_desc" id="form__desc"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="full_container" style="text-align:center; margin-top:50px;">
                <input type="button" class="submit_cancel" value="Cancel" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit_save" value="Save" />
            </div>


        </div><!-- END FORM VIEWPORT -->

    </form>
```

If I try to post with a plain form, that does not involve angular, a simple multipart form with one "file" field, nodejs/multer takes the file and uploads is with no problem, but if 
I use this scenario involving express in the game, it looks like there's no file posted to the server.